# Making Sprite Jump in Pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, event-handling, pygame, sprite

Making a basic game and im trying to get my character to jump when space is pressed

I have a simulated gravity that pulls it down when space is released

but when i push space down it goes up and doesnt stop

i want it to only goo up for like 1 second then go back down

Here is my key press handling code snippet:

```
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.rect.x -= 30
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    self.rect.x += 30
if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    self.rect.y += -20
if key[pygame.K_SPACE] == False:
    self.rect.y += 20
```

like i said this code makes the sprite go up when space is pressed and down when space is released but when it is pressed i want it to wait one second then make the sprite go back down even if the space bar is still down

Please help!!

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things that you should introduce. States and velocity.

In order to make the player fall, we want him to jump only when he is on the ground. So we define 2 states. `STANDING` and `JUMPING`. Now pressing space would only make the player jump if his state is `STANDING`.

To make the player fall like a ball, we introduce `velocity`. When the player is on the ground, we have the velocity set to 0. When you press space, you change the velocity to 100.
In each loop, if the player state is `JUMPING`, we reduce the `velocity` by the Earth's gravity.
The last thing to check, is when the player reaches the ground level, you should set the `velocity` to 0 and player state to `STANDING`.

Comment: that's helpful ill try it out !

Comment: For details on his answer: http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/avoid-game-watch-gravity-in-your-characters-jumps/